# Rails Russian Doll caching, inner fragment's cache is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying out fragment caching for the first time on a mature Rails 7.1.2 app.

I'm trying to cache a collection of partials for an index with fragment caching. The index template renders ok. When I cache the partial, it is cached, and on reload I know the cache is being hit. But the "russian doll" i'm trying to cache within that partial is not saving any HTML.

The "outer" cached partials are based on an AR record `object`, and the "inner" partial is based on a nested AR record, `image`.

I've examined the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) and SO questions about this, but I can't spot what i'm doing wrong, it must be something very simple.

The templates are like this:

```rb
# index.erb
<%= render(partial: "shared/matrix_box",
           collection: @objects, as: :object, cached: true) %>

# shared/matrix_box.erb
<%= matrix_box(columns: columns, id: object_id) do
  tag.div(class: "panel panel-default") do
    concat(
      tag.div(class: "thumbnail-container") do
        cache(image) do             #---------- begin inner fragment --------
          render(partial: "shared/interactive_image",
                 locals: image_args)
        end                         #---------- end inner fragment -----------
      end
    ) if image
    concat(matrix_box_details(presenter, object))
  end
end %>

# shared/interactive_image.erb
<%=
[
  tag.div(class: "image-sizer position-relative mx-auto",
          style: set_width.to_s) do
    [
      tag.div(class: "image-lazy-sizer overflow-hidden",
              style: "padding-bottom: #{presenter.proportion}%;") do
        image_tag("placeholder.svg", presenter.options_lazy)
      end,
      image_stretched_link(presenter.image_link,
                           presenter.image_link_method),
      image_vote_section_html(presenter.image, presenter.votes)
    ].safe_join
  end,
  image_caption(presenter.image, presenter.original)
].safe_join
%>
```

There doesn't seem to be any problem with the HTML. If I eliminate `cache(image) do ... "shared/interactive_image"` in `shared/matrix_box`, the nested interactive_image component renders correctly.

So why does the cache store empty HTML for that image_component? Does it need a comment, like the one declaring a `Template Dependency`? I tried that, and it didn't change anything. In any case, the template is declared.

It seems everything is fairly standard here. Both `object` and `image` are AR models. Caching is enabled in development.

I'm sure the cache is being hit for the `matrix_box` fragment, and also the nested `interactive_image` fragment (under `/images/`).

Here is the development log:

```
Read fragment views/shared/_matrix_box:c38c07ea4460909ff0291cd90161b227/images/1413745-20211114051454000000/en (0.3ms)
...

  Rendered collection of controllers/shared/_matrix_box.erb [24 / 24 cache hits] (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 1075)
```

Does it matter where I call `cache` for the `interactive_image`? I tried calling it both from `shared/matrix_box` and `shared/interactive_image` and it seemed to make no difference.

Calling `cache` from `interactive_image`:

```
  Rendered controllers/shared/_interactive_image.erb (Duration: 7.7ms | Allocations: 3832) [cache miss]
Read fragment views/shared/_interactive_image:ca688eacfd3bc1804fd0f079abf4a7d9/images/1547653-20231203232132000000/en (0.2ms)
Write fragment views/shared/_interactive_image:ca688eacfd3bc1804fd0f079abf4a7d9/images/1547653-20231203232132000000/en (2.2ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is your interesting way of using *erb*, another problem is, unlike other helpers, `cache` helper doesn't capture return value of the block and [relies](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.2/actionview/lib/action_view/buffers.rb#L72) only on the output buffer:

```rb
<%
  cache "test_cache" do
    # this value is not saved into cache
    "cached value"
  end
%>
```

The way you get any output is by sending it to output buffer, there are a few ways to do that, `<%= %>`, `concat`, or just normal text:

```rb
# use erb the way it is meant to be used
<% cache "test_cache" do %>
  <%= "cached value" %>
<% end %>

# or use `concat`
<%
  cache "test_cache" do
    concat "cached value"
  end
%>

# or just text
<% cache "test_cache" do %>
  cached value
<% end %>
```

Output buffer is what gets rendered by the template:

```rb
<%
  p output_buffer
  cache "test_cache" do
    concat "cached value"
  end
  p output_buffer
%>

#=>
# #<ActionView::OutputBuffer:0x00007f2747825fa8 @raw_buffer="">
# Read fragment views/home/show:b58ba51041fc830fcd6ff16f9086fcfe/test_cache (0.1ms)
# #<ActionView::OutputBuffer:0x00007f2747825fa8 @raw_buffer="cached value">
#                                                            ^
```

Comment: Wow. first of all thank you... I always wondered about my erb. I'm coming from php. I always disliked reading "interleaved" php/html with all those opening and closing tags, and got to where I just couldn't stand it and wrote my templates in "pure" php. I think that carried over into erb, and i've been "purging" my templates of html and all those `<%= %>`s the last few months. It requires a lot of ugly concatting, but til now, i never got to the point of understading how it's parsed well enough to know that everything must be concatted, even a cached value. Should I just "interleave"?

Comment: for me, it was harder to read your code. `tag.div` is about 100 times slower than `<div>`. if you dislike all those erb tags, there are other template engines like `slim` or `haml`. for pure ruby approach you might want to consider https://www.phlex.fun/

Comment: I'd never heard of phlex.fun. Seems in some ways preferable to ViewComponent... particularly the nicer templating syntax. Didn't know `tag.div` was slower!!! Is phlex's `div` not also slower? It says "Rendering a Phlex view is significantly faster than rendering an ActionView partial or ViewComponent component" so I guess it's faster! (The reason I was using my "pure (bastardized) erb", other than my difficulty in typing `<%`, is for syntax highlighting - in my editor, the colors are much less noisy and I can instantly spot my locals.)

Comment: most of the time speed is not an issue. anything other than plain html will have some overhead, including phlex, but it gives you object oriented views in return. you don't type `<%`, setup some shortcuts like `%<tab>` or `=<tab>` for erb tags. maybe you just need a different colorscheme for your editor, or you could edit the actual syntax definitions to change one or two noisy colors.

Comment: Ok, finally able to test the code. When I change the line in `shared/matrix_box.erb` to `cache(image) do concat(render(partial(...))) end`, it does render and cache the image partial correctly. However, updating the `image` record via the UI does not invalidate the cache of the image "russian doll". The cache does seem to be storing the `image` with its `id`: `Write fragment views/shared/_matrix_box:8e76e2ad171d417b8316633f78b03f5a/images/1547653-20231203232132000000/en`. (I'm sold on changing my erb style, but to keep the answer intelligible i will continue the syntax above.)

Comment: Just double-checked the db, and i'm certain the image record is being `touch`ed by the image vote UI. The `updated_at` value is fresh. I assume the cache call from the matrix_box partial is keeping track of the image as an AR record, since it is storing the image ID in the cache key there.

Comment: you're caching images `cache(image)` inside of collection of some objects `collection: @objects`. when you update an image, does it update the object? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching note the paragraph about `touch`

Comment: ah - no it does not update the object, and according to our data design, should not. I guess that keeps the `object` cache from sensing the change?  Do i need to manually invalidate the `matrix_box` cache for any object associated with that image, when the image is updated? I was hoping to avoid any manual cache busting...

Comment: when image is updated, `cache(image)` is invalidated, but the collection cache doesn't see any objects updated, there is no way to auto detect that change. all you have to do is to add `touch: true` to the association, you could also use a different datetime column for that `touch: :cached_at`

Comment: by the way, the reason we don't want an image vote to `touch` the object is that the objects index is ordered by `updated_at`, i.e. `recency of significant updates` to the object's data. We don't want an image vote by a third party to count as an update to the object. EDIT: just saw your comment. Yes, a different column seems like a solution! Will the cache pick up changes in that column, or does it only watch `updated_at`?

Comment: you could also do `@objects.each do |obj| cache([obj, obj.image]) do render obj ...` as your top cache, it's slightly slower that collection cache but should do what you need.

Comment: aha ok. Now i understand, that is a key difference between collection cache and regular cache... Incidentally at some point we may have image carousels (like Instagram) and not just the thumbnail image displayed in the `matrix_box` partial, so the new column seems like a more durable solution here — votes on any of the images could `touch` `:cached_at`. But this alternative is very helpful, I'm sure I will use elsewhere.

Comment: oh shoot. it's a `has_many :objects` relation! no can `touch`. I guess I can `touch_all` related objects in the image vote update action.

Comment: `touch_all` works for that, in a controller or model callback. my previous comment probably applies more and without nested image cache.

Comment: I had thought the point of “russian doll” is that an inner cache didn’t have to invalidate the outer cache, but i guess if it’s a collection cache, it's only watching top level objects? If so i get your point in favor of the `@objects.each do |obj| cache([obj, obj.image]) do render obj ...` suggestion, as you said. If i understand, using both records as top-level keys eliminates the need to touch the top object on vote update (which is a db lookup, because it's `has_many` on a big table) but slows caching a bit because it's no longer a simple collection cache.

Comment: "inner cache didn’t have to invalidate the outer cache" - that is 100% incorrect. if you don't invalidate outer cache, inner cache will become stale. "russian doll" cache really makes sense when you have one outer cache and multiple inner caches, so that if one of the inner caches gets invalidated, it invalidates the outer cache, which means you'll have to rerender the inner invalidated record but other records will stay cached, and then the outer cache will be updated. note that collection cache doesn't create a single outer cache, it caches each record individually.

Comment: just think in terms of cache keys, if a cache key is not updated you will serve stale data. if it is a nested cache, you have to invalidate all the caches above it.